# Java. Компонент с произвольным количеством столбцов

Tags: java, listview, list, компоненты

Здравствуйте! Есть ли в Java аналог ListView из WinAPI ? Необходимо хранить n столбцов с последующей сортировкой. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду фреймворки GUI где есть что то подобное?

Comment: @BogdanBida Да, пока нашёл только JTable

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подойдет ListView в фреймворке JavaFX

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужны столбцы, то это явно уже контрол таблица. В JavaFX есть такой, называется [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html)